# TextView value goes on multiple ExpandableListView children

Tags: android, onclicklistener, expandablelistview

I'm using an `ExpandableListView` and I have an `adapter` for it. Now, on a child click, I get a `dialog` box with an `EditText` field, and the value entered in that `EditText` is supposed to go in a `TextView` field inside the child clicked. This seems to work, but when I expand another header of the `ExpListView`, that value goes inside some of the other children's `TextViews`. How can I fix this?

Here's my code for that:

ExpandableListAdapter:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;

private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<Artikl>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<Artikl>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Artikl child = (Artikl) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    final String childText = child.getNaziv();
    final String cenaArtikl = Integer.toString(child.getCena());

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.from_name);

    TextView txtCena = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.cena_view);


    txtCena.setText(cenaArtikl);
    txtListChild.setText(childText);

    return convertView;
}



@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
@Override public boolean areAllItemsEnabled(){
    return true;
}


}
```

OnChildClickListener for the ExpListView children

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Order.this);
            final EditText input = new EditText(Naracka.this);
            final int GP = groupPosition;
            final View vi = v;
            final int CP=childPosition;
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            input.setLayoutParams(lp);

            builder.setMessage( listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                    + " : "
                    + listDataChild.get(
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                    childPosition).getNaziv())
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setView(input)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.editText);
                            text.setText(input.getText().toString());

dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

            //Creating dialog box
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            //Setting the title manually
            alert.setTitle("Enter amount");
            alert.show();
        return false;

        }
    });
```

EDIT: Here's the Artikl Model code, it's just a model with getters and setters:

```
public class Artikl {
private String sifra, naziv;
private int cena;


public Artikl() {
}

public Artikl(String sifra, String naziv, int cena
            ) {
    this.naziv = naziv;
    this.sifra = sifra;
    this.cena = cena;


}

public String getNaziv() {
    return naziv;
}

public void setNaziv(String name) {
    this.naziv = name;
}


public String getSifra() {
    return sifra;
}

public void setSifra(String sifra) {
    this.sifra = sifra;
}

public int getCena() {
    return cena;
}

public void setCena(int cena) {
    this.cena = cena;
}
```

}

Here are the screenshots (sorry that the app is not in English)
[So, I enter the amount on the second child here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llnux.png) , and then when I expand the first header, I get it [Here too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVJe1.png)

Comment: can you post the picture of the app with expandable list view..

Comment: Please add your Artikl file too in your question.

Comment: I edited the post so you have the code and screenshots there